# Can a lambda capturing nothing access global variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, global-variables, standards

```
int n;    
int main()
{
    [](){ n = 0; }(); // clang says "ok"

    int m;
    [](){ m = 0; }(); // clang says "not ok"
}
```

I just wonder:

If the lambda captures nothing, is it allowed to access global variables as per the C++ standard?

Comment: I would assume so, given that you can use other global things (functions and types) without capturing them. Imagine if you had to capture C++ algorithm functions (`std::find` for example) in order to use them from lambdas.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda says something about `capture-default`. I couldn't figure out in details what it does.

Comment: If you think about it a lambda is just a short-cut to defining a `struct` with a function operator. Local variables are not in scope for `struct` member functions but global variables are.

Comment: Global variables _can't_ be captured.

Comment: @cpplearner "Global variables can't be captured. "? Any reference?

Comment: @John http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#4.sentence-1 (Please don't ask questions in comments. StackOverflow has "[ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)" for a reason.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, sure. Normal name lookup rules apply.

> **[expr.prim.lambda]/7** ... for purposes of name lookup ... the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*.

Re: why local variables are treated differently from global ones.

> **[expr.prim.lambda]/13** ... If a *lambda-expression* or an instantiation of the function call operator template of a generic lambda odr-uses (3.2) `this` or a variable with automatic storage duration from its reaching scope, that entity shall be captured by the *lambda-expression*.
>
> **[expr.prim.lambda]/9** A *lambda-expression* whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope (3.3.3) is a *local lambda expression*... The *reaching scope* of a local lambda expression is the set of enclosing scopes up to and including the innermost enclosing function and its parameters.

In your example, `m` is a variable with automatic storage duration from the lambda's reaching scope, and so shall be captured. `n` is not, and so doesn't have to be.

Comment: The given citation says nothing related to global variables.

Comment: If `n` is local, the code is illegal. Why is it legal if `n` is global?

Comment: @xmllmx Added the explanation for why local variables behave differently.

Answer (score 14):

Actually the `[](){ n = 10; }();` doesn't capture anything, it uses the global variable instead.

```
int n;    
int main()
{
    [](){ n = 10; }(); // clang says "ok"
    std::cout << n; // output 10
}
```

See [capture-list in Explaination](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

> **capture-list**  -   a comma-separated list of zero or more captures, optionally beginning with a capture-default.
>
> Capture list can be passed as follows (see below for the detailed
>   description):
>
> - [a,&b] where a is captured by copy and b is captured by reference.
> - [this] captures the current object (*this) by reference
> - [&] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by reference and current object by reference if exists
> - [=] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by copy and current object by reference if exists
> - **[ ] captures nothing**

Comment: "***current object by reference*** if exists"? What's that? Could you please explain that in more detail?

Answer (score 10):

Global, static and const variables are accessed by default:

```
#include <iostream>

int n;    
int main()
{
    [](){ n = 10; }();
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    static int m = 1;
    [](){ m = 100; }();
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
    const int l = 200;
    [](){ std::cout << l << std::endl; }();
}
```

Comment: What makes `const int l` "accessible by default"? What are the rules here? Can I make my custom type accessible by default as well? (EDIT: I can, I had to use  `constexpr` and my object was accessible )