# Local reference to std::cout captured by lambda without asking for it

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17

Have I lost my mind? Was this always permitted?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto& os = std::cout;

    auto write = []()
    {
        os << "what\n";
    };

    write();
}
```

I'm using:

> Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0

Though also see on Coliru:

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12df10ed23d6aa44))

I always thought an empty capture would not capture anything.

Indeed, MSDN [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx):

> An empty capture clause, [ ], indicates that the body of the lambda expression accesses no variables in the enclosing scope.

Further research suggests that this is in fact okay for capturing `const` things (which I also didn't know, but whatever), but `os` is not `const` (no reference is! though it *is* immutable…).

I came across this when turning on `-Wextra` and noticing that Clang thought a `&os` capture (which is present in my real code) was unnecessary. Removing it I was staggered to find the build worked.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827651/can-a-lambda-capturing-nothing-access-global-variables

Comment: @papagaga: No, no, no.  This is about const automatics.

Comment: global variables are in scope without capture

Comment: I get source>: In lambda function:

<source>:9:9: error: 'os' is not captured

         os << "what\n";

         ^~ (godbolt gcc 7.2 C++17)

Comment: @papagaga `os` is not global. Although the thing it refers to is. ..... ah.

Comment: Oddly works with gcc 8.2...

Comment: [I've tripped up on this before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47592474/560648). Except here the behaviour seems to be the inverse.

Comment: msvc 19.14 [rejects it](https://godbolt.org/z/wlyO1r)

Comment: clang also accepts this, so it's basically inference that makes it work?

Comment: Interesting. This looks like an optimization bug, where the compiler "sees through" the reference before ensuring that the reference itself is okay to use.

Comment: yes, so moving the lambda away in a function makes it fail, so it's inference (perhaps not optimization?)

Comment: no need to capture if it "is a non-local variable or has **static** or thread local storage duration". Could it be that?

Comment: @papagaga Guess it depends whether we consider `os` to be a local variable with automatic storage duration, or equivalent to its referent. Though as noted above results seem to vary. (I'm going to have to capture `[&]` to avoid the warning and get a good build in all cases, I think.)

Comment: @rustyx: it seems that references must be captured independently when they don't refer to a global object. For instance: `#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    auto& os = i;

    auto write = [&i]()
    {
        std::cout << os;
    };

    write();
}` will trigger

Comment: @rustyx : Indeed they are not variables, but lambdas do not capture variables, they capture _entities_, and all of values, objects, and references constitute entities ([basic]/3).

Comment: There's a [defect report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34865) opened covering that case and it seem not restricted for `std::cout`

Comment: @Jans and that is worthy of an answer!

Comment: IMO the code should be allowed:  `int &r = n;` indicates that `r` and `n` are two names for the same variable. There shouldn't be any case where the expression `r` behaves differently to the expression `n`. The lambda can use `n` without capture so it should be able to use `r` too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's an open [clang report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34865) that cover the case of implicit capture of references by lambda expressions, this is not limited to `std::cout` but to references variable that are found to refer to constant expressions.

For more reference, the backing defect report on the CWG is [CWG-1472](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1472)

**EDIT:**

Based on @Rakete1111 comment, I should have pointed out explicitly that clang is right in accepting the code,
which is the result of applying the CWG defect mentioned above. The report was reopened because of
diagnosis location not because they were wrong about the acceptance

Comment: That's the badger! Thanks Jans.

Comment: Are you implying that clang is wrong to accept the code?

Comment: @Rakete1111 No, As Richard said in the report, when the reference variable is found to refer to constant expression, the referenced variable is used instead of the reference variable itself, the issue was reopened by diagnosis location not because they were wrong about the reference.